# How to download images from the web page?

Tags: python, image, web-scraping

I have a python script that searches for images on a web page and it's supposed to download them to folder named 'downloaded'. Last 2-3 lines are  problematic, I don't know how to write the correct 'with open' code.

The biggest part of the script is fine, lines 42-43 give an error

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

downloadDirectory = "downloaded"
baseUrl = "http://pythonscraping.com"

def getAbsoluteURL(baseUrl, source):
    if source.startswith("http://www."):
        url = "http://"+source[11:]
    elif source.startswith("http://"):
        url = source
    elif source.startswith("www."):
        url = source[4:]
        url = "http://"+source
    else:
        url = baseUrl+"/"+source
    if baseUrl not in url:
        return None
    return url 

def getDownloadPath(baseUrl, absoluteUrl, downloadDirectory):
    path = absoluteUrl.replace("www.", "")
    path = path.replace(baseUrl, "")
    path = downloadDirectory+path
    directory = os.path.dirname(path)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    return path


html = requests.get("http://www.pythonscraping.com")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
downloadList = bsObj.find_all(src=True)

for download in downloadList:
    fileUrl = getAbsoluteURL(baseUrl,download["src"])
    if fileUrl is not None:
        print(fileUrl)
    with open(fileUrl, getDownloadPath(baseUrl, fileUrl, downloadDirectory), 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(fileUrl.content)
```

It opens downloaded folder on my computer and misc folder within it. And it gives a traceback error.
Traceback:

```
http://pythonscraping.com/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\kodovi\downloaded.py", line 43, in <module>
    with open(fileUrl, getDownloadPath(baseUrl, fileUrl, downloadDirectory), 'wb
') as out_file:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your downloadList includes some URLs that aren't images.  You could instead look for any `<img>` tags in the HTML:

```
downloadList = bsObj.find_all('img')
```

Then use this to download those images:

```
for download in downloadList:
    fileUrl = getAbsoluteURL(baseUrl,download["src"])
    r = requests.get(fileUrl, allow_redirects=True)
    filename = os.path.join(downloadDirectory, fileUrl.split('/')[-1])
    open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

EDIT: I've updated the `filename = ...` line so that it writes the file of the same name to the directory in the string `downloadDirectory`.  By the way, the normal convention for Python variables is not to use camel case.

Comment: Thanks. This does downloaded images but not in the folder 'downloaded'. Practically, with your code function getDownloadPath is ommited. Is there any way that we add it so that pictures are downloaded to that folder?

Comment: Also what this fileUrl.split('/')[-1] means? That it takes only what comes after the last forward slash, in other words jpg file?

Comment: You mean, "What does `fileUrl.split('/')[-1]` mean?"?  The `fileUrl.split('/')` part means, "Take the string `fileUrl`, break it up anywhere a forward slash appears, and create a list out of all the pieces."  Then the [-1] at the end means, "Take the very last element of the list."  Thus, you get back the text in the URL that shows up after the final forward slash.  Note that if `fileUrl` itself ends in a slash instead of just the filename, then this will return an empty string.

Comment: As for using the 'downloaded' folder, I've updated that line that defines the filename.

Comment: Bill M. your newest solution gives traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\kodovi\downloaded.py", line 44, in <module>
    open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'downloaded\\lrg_0.jpg'

Comment: What, exactly, are you expecting the the path of "filename" to be?  Aren't you trying to just download the file "lrg_0.jpg" to a local folder name "downloaded"?  You could just replace the value for `downloadDirectory` to some absolute path on your machine.

Comment: I would like that script first creates local folder and then downloads images to it.

Comment: You mean "I would like that script to first create the local folder" if it doesn't exist?  Then earlier in your code, you could use `if not os.path.exists(downloadDirectory)` to see if the directory exists, and if it doesn't, run `os.makedirs(downloadDirectory)`.